# R file not generated with ActionBarSherlock 4.4.0 and aapt.exe stopped working

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using Sherlock 4.4.0 and the R file just won't generate.
I imported the actionbarsherlock as a library project. It's minSDKVersion=7 and targetSdkVersion=17. My own project's setting is the same.

The order and export setting of the library project is like this
[image]

The order and export setting of the my own project is like this
[image]

The version of my android sdk are all the newest:
[image]

And everytime I clean the projects, the aapt.exe will stop working.

What should I do?

Edited:
I was using the official ActionBar and it works, and there was some reason making me switch to ActionBarSherlock. After I removed the support.v7.appcompat from my project and added actionbarsherlock as a library, the error rised.

Comment: Any error or problem in the Eclipse console?

Comment: try check marking android 4.2.2 also.